# Class in a Structure in C++

Tags: c++

Can we define a Class within a Structure? If yes then how? And what will be the syntax of that?

Comment: Do I detect that "Jay, spammer extraordinary"  is back with us?

Comment: I think so.   I answered his question in good faith, and may now regret that.

Comment: @Piotr One "jay" was spamming SO with trivial questions about a month or so ago. He was put in the penalty box, but I think his time there has expired.

Comment: @Neil- hey, don't mess with me someone else..

Comment: Jay, you have failed to accept answers to your questions.   You won't get any more answers from me, and I support future attempts to boycott & blacklist you.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  Here is an example of declaration, implementation, and usage.

**Declaration**

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int m_Int_in_Struct;

    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            MyClass(); // default constructor
            int m_Int_in_Class;
    };
};
```

**Implementation**

```
MyStruct::MyClass::MyClass() // Constructor Implementation
{
    m_Int_in_Class = 5; 
}
```

**Usage**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyStruct::MyClass* newObject = new MyStruct::MyClass();
    newObject->m_Int_in_Class = 10;
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If this is what you wanted, please mark the answer as "Accepted" (the check-mark on the left-side, near the Up-Down voting.).

Comment: And you can also simply say "`struct MyStruct`" instead of `typedef`ing an anonymous struct.

Comment: @sth:  You are correct, but I'm very old-school.  That wasn't always possible, and old habits die hard. :)

Comment: @abelenky:  I believe it's always been possible to use "struct MyStruct" in C++, but it was illegal in (at least) C90.

Comment: I changed my answer to the plain "struct [name]" format.  (hope I got it right... final semi-colon?)

Comment: Here's a question for you.  If "MyStruct" was a POD before, and you add the class into the definition, is "MyStruct" still a POD?

Comment: @Richard:  I'm not 100% sure, but I think so.  In my example, class is a definition that happens to appear inside the struct.  But definitions don't take up any memory.  I still expect sizeof(MyStruct)==4.

Answer (score 2):

Structure in C++ is ordinary class with all members public.
Because you can nest one class declaration in another class declaration (creating nested class) you can do the same within a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. For example:

```
struct A
{
    bool _a;
    int  _aa;

    class B
    {
        int _b;
        public:
        B(const int bb):_b(bb){}
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that `class`-members are private by default, while `struct`-members default to public. So defining a class inside a struct works the same way as defining a class inside another class:

```
struct A {
  class B {};
  B b;
};

A::B b2;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct s1
{
    class c1
    {
            int n;
            public:

    };
};
```

Comment: This code has a dangling "public:", isn't formatted, or code-blocked, and has no explanation or supporting material.  I'm shocked it got an up-vote, and I am down-voting.